# ¿Como logro copiar todas las filas de un datagridview en c# en un solo archivo de texto?

Tags: c#

tengo un problema con mi programa. Necesito hacer que a la hora de que copie todos las filas del `DatagridView` las almacene en el mismo archivo y las muestre en el orden que están en el `DatagridView`, por favor necesito de su ayuda. Les comparto el código ya que por el momento solo esta volviendo a escribir en el mismo archivo

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\GUSTAVO\Desktop\proyecto de restaurante\factura\"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\GUSTAVO\Desktop\proyecto de restaurante\factura\");
    }

    int rowcount = menu.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
    {
        TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\GUSTAVO\Desktop\proyecto de restaurante\factura\Archivo.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(menu.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "\t"
                     + menu.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "\t"
                      + menu.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "\t"
                       + menu.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "\n");
        sw.Close();
    }
    MessageBox.Show(@"Datos Exportados correctamente");


}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. No se entiende muy bien tu pregunta. Te refieres a que cada vez que exportas los datos se sobreescribe el archivo? Si es asi, prueba a añadir `true` a tu `StreamWriter`: `TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\GUSTAVO\Desktop\proyecto de restaurante\factura\Archivo.txt",true);`

Answer (score 1):

Corregidme si me equivoco, pero tanto el `TextWriter` como el `.Close()` deberían ir fuera del for. Uno encima y otro abajo:

```
int rowcount = menu.Rows.Count;
TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\GUSTAVO\Desktop\proyecto de restaurante\factura\Archivo.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
{

    sw.WriteLine(menu.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "\t"
                 + menu.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "\t"
                  + menu.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "\t"
                   + menu.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "\n");

}
sw.Close();
```

De lo contrario estas abriendo un writer, reescribiendo el archivo y cerrando el writer **por cada fila de tu datagrid**. Con lo cual tu archivo solo va a contener la última fila del datagrid al estar reescribiéndose una y otra vez.

Comment: Aparte, lo mas recomendado es un "using": using(var sw = new StreamWriter....). De esta forma te aseguras que se cierre el archivo ya que el using, al cerrarse, libera los recursos, y por ende, cierra el archivo.